# Get select multiple values in PHP

Tags: php, html

I try to get values of multiple select in html form.

I add the brackets in my 'name' attribute, but it still doesn't work.

I use a 'framework' written in a course, there is the full exemple : https://github.com/bpesquet/MonBlog/

form

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?controleur=Creer&action=addFilm" style="display:none" id="addFilm">

  <label>Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" required> <br>

  <label>Release date</label>
  <input type="date" name="release" required> <br>

  <label>Synopsis</label>
  <textarea name="synopsis"></textarea> <br>

  <label>Nationality</label>
  <select name="nationality[]" multiple>
    <?php foreach($pays as $payss): ?>
      <option><?= $payss['nom_pays'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select> <br>

  <label>Genre</label>
  <select name="genre[]" multiple>
    <?php foreach($genres as $genre): ?>
      <option><?= $genre['nom_genre']  ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select> <br>

  <label>File name</label>
  <input type="text" name="filename" required> <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I fill select element with php from a database.

My $_POST variable is

`Array ( [title] => test_film [release] => 2000-11-20 [synopsis] => [nationality] => USA [genre] => Comedy [filename] => test )`

(only the last element is selected as a string)

When i look for the request in my navigator i have the correct POST parameters
It look like this :

```
title: "test_film"
release: "2000-11-11"
synopsis: ""
nationality: [2]
    [0]: "USA"
    [1]: "France"
genre: [2]
    [0]: "Thriller"
    [1]: "Comedy"
filename: "test"
```

But variable 'genre' is not an array in $_POST

Comment: Make print_r($_POST) and show us.

Comment: Try to add `value` attribute to your options tag
<option value="<?= $genre['nom_genre']  ?>"><?= $genre['nom_genre']  ?></option>

Comment: I really don't understand. 
I add 'value' property as @noctilux says yesterday and it works.
I remove it today and it still works ...

Answer (score 0):

Everything works normally with your code, I think just the way you print out variable is not proper:
Try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);die;
```